# pandasql: How to select non english named column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandasql

Dataframe has non english named columns, how to select such columns?

```
import pandasql as pdsql

pysql = lambda q: pdsql.sqldf(q, globals())
sqlquery = 'select ''Машина'', min(''Дата доставки'') from days_ans group by 1'
pysql(sqlquery)
```

Last row returns an error:

> PandaSQLException: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "доставки": syntax error [SQL: 'select Машина, min(Дата доставки) from days_ans group by 1']

PS Without specifying columns- works as should:

```
sqlquery = 'select * from days_ans limit 1'
sqlquery = 'select ''Партнер'' from days_ans limit 1'
```

I think the problem is related to the columns with spaces in it

Comment: `'aa''bb'` becomes `'aabb'`. In your example `Партнер` has no whitespaces while `Дата доставки` does, which gives SQL syntax error. Use different quotes (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single quotes `''` concatenate and become nothing. Try to use double quotes at the both sides of a string instead:

```
>>> sqlquery = 'select ''Машина'', min(''Дата доставки'') from days_ans group by 1'
>>> sqlquery
'select Машина, min(Дата доставки) from days_ans group by 1'
>>> sqlquery = "select ''Машина'', min(''Дата доставки'') from days_ans group by 1"
>>> sqlquery
"select ''Машина'', min(''Дата доставки'') from days_ans group by 1"
```

[String literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/string-catenation.html)

Comment: Wow, never thought about differences " vs ''